# What exactly is a Fock state?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, definition, quantum-states

I am a bit confused by the way a Fock state is defined and hope to find some clarification.

The Fock space is defined as the direct sum of all $n$-particle Hilbertspaces $H_i$

$$F =  H_0 \oplus H_1 \oplus H_2 \oplus  ...$$

Let $|\Phi \rangle$ be a $m$-particle state. Obviously $|\Phi \rangle \in H_m$ is a true statement. However I am wondering wether $|\Phi \rangle$ itself is a Fock state

$$|\Phi \rangle \in F$$

or a state that looks like

$$|\Phi \rangle_F = 0 \oplus 0 \oplus ... \oplus |\Phi \rangle \oplus ... $$

Comment: I changed $\bigoplus$ to $\oplus$ because it improved formatting imo. If there is any significance to `\bigoplus` that I'm not aware of, feel free to change it back.

Comment: @Jonas `\bigoplus` is often used as the direct sum variant of the standard summation symbol (i.e. $\displaystyle \bigoplus_{n=0}^\infty H_n=H_0 \oplus H_1 \oplus \ldots$) so your edit is good.

Comment: the previous to last belong to hilbert space, the last one to focker space

Comment: The last equation doesn't make much sense to me. What do you mean with the direct sum of zeroes and a state $\vert \Phi\rangle$?

Comment: The most general form of a Fock state is some vector like this: $| \Psi \rangle = |0\rangle \oplus \sum_i a_i | \phi_i \rangle \oplus \sum_{i,j} | a_{i,j} \phi_i, \phi_j \rangle \oplus ...$. The "direct sum of zeros" should emphazise, that all coefficients $a_i, a_{i,j} ,...$ are equal to zero except for the ones the state $| \Phi \rangle$ is made up.

Comment: Silly question maybe: what does the 'Big O Plus' symbol mean?

Comment: @Gert $\oplus$ typically refers to the direct sum, in this case the direct sum of Hilbert spaces.  $\bigoplus_{n=0}^\infty$ is to $\oplus$ as $\sum_{n=0}^\infty$ is to $+$.

Comment: A technical comment on the OP (v3).  The direct sum $\mathscr H := \bigoplus_{n=0}^\infty H_n$ is the space of all multiparticle vectors $c_0^{(0)} + \sum_i c_i^{(1)}\phi_i + \sum_{ij} c_{ij}^{(2)}\phi_i \otimes \phi_j + \ldots$ such that all but finitely many coefficients are zero.  The Fock space is the Hilbert completion of $\mathscr H$, which consists of all vectors which can be written as the limit of a Cauchy sequence of elements of $\mathscr H$.

Comment: @j Murray Thank you. Slightly above my paygrade, methinks...

Answer (score 3):

The direct sum $\oplus$ maps a pair of Hilbert spaces to a larger Hilbert space. It doesn't directly act on individual states in the Hilbert space.

A generic Fock space state would look like
\begin{equation}
|\Psi \rangle = a_0|0 \rangle + \sum_i a_i |\phi_i\rangle + \sum_{ij} a_{ij} |\phi_i, \phi_j \rangle + \cdots
\end{equation}
where $|\phi_i \rangle$ are a basis for the one particle states.

You *could* write a generic $n$ particle state as
\begin{equation}
|\Psi \rangle = 0 |0\rangle + \sum_i 0 |\phi_i\rangle + \cdots + \sum_{i_1, \cdots, i_n} a_{i_1 \cdots i_n} |\phi_{i_1} \cdots \phi_{i_n}\rangle + \cdots
\end{equation}
But most people don't write terms that are identically zero unless they are making some kind of point. Therefore a more common way to write an $n$ particle state is simply
\begin{equation}
|\Psi \rangle =  \sum_{i_1, \cdots, i_n} a_{i_1 \cdots i_n} |\phi_{i_1} \cdots \phi_{i_n}\rangle 
\end{equation}