# States of the Fock space and the Hilbert space

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, second-quantization

The Fock space is defined as the direct sum of all $n$-particle Hilbert spaces. Are Hilbert space vectors also Fock space vectors or are they just isomorphic to Fock space vectors?

Comment: Could you elaborate the difference between this question and [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/675836/what-exactly-is-a-fock-state) one (a question by OP)?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct me if I am wrong, but I think it can be thought of through a simpler case. What I mean is that your question is the same as asking if $a \in \mathbb{R}$ is also an element of $\mathbb{R}^n = \bigoplus^n_{i=0} \mathbb{R}$. Obviously no, because $\mathbb{R}^n$ is a vector space, which means that if $a$ were an element of the n-dimensional space then we would need a way to add a scalar and an n-dimensional vector, which in most cases is not logical (emphasis on in most cases).

However *we can* represent $a$ in a way that belongs to $\mathbb{R}^n$, but that we can agree to identify with $a$. For example, if $a = 1$ we might say that in $\mathbb{R}^3$ $a = (0, 0, 1)$.

In short, yes, they are isomorphic.